# how to import passwords generated by ruby's scrypt into firebase?

Tags: ruby, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-encryption, scrypt

I'm attempting to import scrypted hashes generated by ruby's [scrypt](http://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt) into Firebase.

Ruby's scrypt doesn't define (that I can tell) what it's output is.  It looks like this:

```
[1] pry(main)> SCrypt::Password.create("somepassword")
=> "400$8$3a$a5063a5e21eb268f$4e93e29c3511a6e44900c251a11dc4f6db17cfc7f5ae0272a4b6179804474037"
```

Firebase, on the other hand, expects several inputs described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth).  They are:

- hash-key (required)
- salt-separator (optional)
- rounds (required)
- mem-cost (required)
- password hash (required)
- password salt (required)

**So, how do I map from the scrypted hash to those inputs?**

---

Digging in a bit, if you add a debugger and output this [thing](https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/blob/master/lib/scrypt.rb#L232) then you can see the salt is part of SCrypt::Password's output:

```
[1] pry(main)> hashed_password = SCrypt::Password.create('somepassword')
400$8$37$7be9f9deb4e3b1ea
=> "400$8$37$7be9f9deb4e3b1ea$8f9d51c642c4a40341613093bde6935cccc7d6af379eedfe900476f3bec6fbde"
[2] pry(main)> split = hashed_password.split('$')
=> ["400", "8", "37", "7be9f9deb4e3b1ea", "8f9d51c642c4a40341613093bde6935cccc7d6af379eedfe900476f3bec6fbde"]
# salt
[3] pry(main)> split[0,4].join('$')
=> "400$8$37$7be9f9deb4e3b1ea"
```

But we're still missing a few things.  IMO, the 'hash-key' is the biggest question mark.  Scrypt (the gem) doesn't get initialized anywhere - so there's no key stored specific to my application.  It also doesn't appear to be part of the hashed output - so it's not stored with that either.  That said, Firebase expects it as a command line arg, which implies it's re-used for every password, and thus some kind of global setting.  Those don't seem to add up.

Comment: You asked a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43596188/importing-users-and-their-scrypted-passwords-into-firebase-authentication which was closed for being too broad. What has changed between this question and that? Per the documentation, SCrypt will tell you `salt`, `cost` and `hash` for a password. Can you show us code you've written using the SCrypt interface? Currently it looks like you're not working with that API or from its documentation.

Comment: There are still a pile of unknowns.  Does Scrypt::Password#cost == Google's definition of 'mem-cost' ?  What is 'rounds'? What is 'hash-key'? Possibly knowing 3 of the values doesn't equate to knowing 5 and successfully importing these passwords.  There's no code.  I can't possibly try or test anything until I at least have something for each of those params as the CLI requires them and is rather opaque.